# How to pass a parameter list to another function in Python?

Tags: python, argv, optparse, keyword-argument

Using `optparse`, I want to separate the list of option list parameters from the place where I call add_option().  How do I package the stuff up in File A (and then unpack in file B) so that this will work?  The parser_options.append() lines will not work as written...

File A:

```
import file_b
parser_options = []
parser_options.append(('-b', '--bootcount', type='string', dest='bootcount', default='', help='Number of times to repeat booting and testing, if applicable'))
parser_options.append(('-d', '--duration', type='string', dest='duration', default='', help='Number of hours to run the test.  Decimals OK'))

my_object = file_b.B(parser_options)
```

File B recieves parser_options as input:

```
import optparse
class B:
    def __init__(self, parser_options):
        self.parser = optparse.OptionParser('MyTest Options')
        if parser_options:
            for option in parser_options: 
                self.parser.add_option(option)
```

*** EDIT: Fixed to use ojbects

Comment: `import file_A`? What is the flow of control?

Comment: Where is `build_parser()` called?

Comment: This is just a snippet because there are objects involved and that would be a lot to post.  I'm just trying to give the flavor of the problem.  I need to pass these parser_options from one object to another.

Comment: **Note**: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to shoehorn your options into some data structure, wouldn't it be simpler to define a function in file A that adds options to a parser you give it?

File A:

```
def addOptions(parser):
    parser.add_option('-b', '--bootcount', type='string', dest='bootcount', default='', help='Number of times to repeat booting and testing, if applicable')
    parser.add_option('-d', '--duration', type='string', dest='duration', default='', help='Number of hours to run the test.  Decimals OK')
```

File B:

```
import optparse
def build_parser(parser_options):
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('MyTest Options')
    if parser_options:
        parser_options(parser)
```

elsewhere:

```
import file_a
import file_b
file_b.build_parser(file_a.addOptions)
```

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler, but I am passing the parser_options to an object at construction as the parse needs to happen in __init__.  So there is nothing in the object that I can call before it is constructed.

Comment: I updated the example to show the problem...I don't have a file C that imports them both

Comment: There's no reason it has to be in a separate file. You can do the "elsewhere" bit in file a just as well, without importing file_a.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're trying to pass keyword arguments in a tuple. The code `('-b', '--bootcount', type='string', dest='bootcount', default='', help='Number of times to repeat booting and testing, if applicable')` is only legal in a function call, not anywhere else. The `type='string'` bits are not legal in a tuple!

If you want to pass function arguments around, you need to use a list or tuple for the positional arguments and a dictionary for the keyword arguments. Here's one way you can do that by changing your single tuple for a tuple containing an `args` tuple and a `kwargs` dictionary:

```
parser_options = []
parser_options.append((('-b', '--bootcount'),
                       dict(type='string', dest='bootcount', default='',
                            help='Number of times to repeat booting and testing, if applicable')))
parser_options.append((('-d', '--duration'),
                       dict(type='string', dest='duration', default='',
                            help='Number of hours to run the test.  Decimals OK')))
```

In your other file, you can pass the contents of the tuple and dict to the appropriate function using the `*` and `**` operators to unpack the arguments:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, parser_options)
        self.parser = optparse.OptionParser('MyTest Options')
        if parser_options:
            for args, kwargs in parser_options: 
                self.parser.add_option(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the struct I was looking for.  You answered the question that I was ultimately asking, and Phil Frost helped me find a more straightforward way to do what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing the parser to the object at construction, which is nice because I can name it from the calling module:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser('My Diagnostics')
parser.add_option('-p', '--pbootcount', type='string', dest='pbootcount', default='testing1234', help=' blah blah')
c = myobject.MyObject(parser)
```